# What type of z transform is this?

Tags: z-transform, laplace-transform

I am trying to understand this equation:

[image]

It comes from:

$Force = mass * acceleration$

$F(t) = m * a(t)$

$F(s) = m * (s^2 * y(s) - s*y0 - y0)$, where $y0=0$

$F(s) = m * s^2 * y(s)$

$y(s) =  F(s)/(m*s^2)$

Then I don't understand what type of substitution they are using for s. It appears they substitute:

$s =  (1-z^{-1})/T$

And then the last $z^{-1}$ is just to indicate they are delaying the whole thing one sample for another reason.

What type of s substitution is this called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [these notes.](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~pyo22/mem640/lecture03-Discrete/mem640Lecture-Discrete.pdf)

In particular, this slide:

[image: Indirect design approach]

shows that using a **backward difference model** sets up the approximation:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \approx \frac{z - 1}{Tz} = \frac{1 - z^{-1}}{T}
$$

There are many ways to approximate the continuous-time derivative with discrete-time difference operations. That's all that substitution is doing: choosing one way of making the approximation.

Comment: Got it. So it's the backward difference model. Is it easiest for someone without a lot of knowledge to just do trial and error to see which method will work in a given situation? I was trying something before and either the backward or forward difference didn't work but Tustin's did. Is Tustin's usually the safest bet?

Comment: @mike  The closer you approximate the "real" derivative operation, the better (in general).  You could go even more complex, but Tustin's (trapezoidal) method is usually accurate enough for most operations.

Answer (score 0):

> What type of s substitution is this called?

This isn't a z transform per se.  It's a method (called backwards difference) to *approximate* the transfer function of a system sampled time given a transfer function in continuous time.